# How to count the occurrences of a word in the output of a command

Tags: shell-script, grep, variable

First I am executing the below command.

Command executed:

```bsh
/app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status
```

Output of the command:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: follower
```

I want to grep with the word "follower" and print the total count of that word (`grep 'follower' | wc -l`).

Issue I am facing here is that I am not able to put the output of the command to a variable it is throwing "command not found".

```bsh
-bash-4.2$ cat zookeeper.sh
#!/bin/bash
ZK_STATUS = ` /app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status `
ABC = $ZK_STATUS | grep 'follower' | wc -l
echo $ABC
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./zookeeper.sh
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
./zookeeper.sh: line 2: ZK_STATUS: command not found
./zookeeper.sh: line 4: ABC: command not found
0
```

Comment: Do you also want to count the word `followers`, if it happened to occur? I'm also noting that your code seems to try to count _lines_ containing the word, not the word itself (if it was to occur several times in one line).  Is that an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The errors are because you have spaces before and after the `=` in the assignment.  This is an error in shell scripts.

   Use `var=value`, not `var = value`.  Otherwise, the shell will try to execute a program called `var` - hence the `command not found` error messages.
2. You need to use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to get the output of a command into a variable.  e.g.

   ```
   ZK_STATUS=$(/app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status)
   ```
3. `grep` has a `-c` option to count the number of matching lines, so `wc -l` isn't needed.

   ```
   ZK_STATUS=$(/app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status)
   ABC=$(printf '%s' "$ZK_STATUS" | grep -c follower)
   ```

   Or, more directly,

   ```
   ABC=$(/app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status |
         grep -c follower)
   ```
4. If you want to count each individual occurrence of `follower` (rather than just count the number of lines in which the word appears at least once) then you can't use `grep -c`.

   Instead, do something like:

   ```
   ABC=$(printf '%s' "$ZK_STATUS" | grep -o follower | wc -l)
   ```

   `grep -o` will print every match on its own line.  `wc -l` then counts those lines.

Comment: ABC=$(printf '%s' "$ZK_STATUS" | grep -c follower) what does printf '%s'  here?

Comment: grep -c will display only count of lines where content occurs . suppose in same line if content occurs 3 times. grep -c it will print "1" where content  3 times

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS  yes. so does piping to `wc -l`.

Comment: @KameshM  '%s' is a printf format specification for a string of any length.   `echo` would work just as well in this case, but I mostly prefer `printf` - it works in all situations, no matter what I'm printing, whereas `echo` can fail badly, depending on what I'm trying to print with it or which version of `echo` I'm using.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` or compatible and a given non-empty string not containing newline nor NUL characters:

```
string=follower
```

To count the number of lines containing that string in the output of some `cmd`:

```
count=$(
  cmd | grep -cFe "$string"
)
```

To count the number of non-overlapping occurrences of that string:

```
count=$(
  cmd | grep -oFe "$string" | wc -l
)
```

For the number of possibly overlapping occurrences (for instance, to consider that there are 3 occurrences of `did` in `dididid`, not just 2):

```
count=$(
  cmd | grep -Poe "(?=\Q$string\E)." | wc -l
)
```

(here also assuming that `$string` doesn't contain `\E`)

If you want to find the `$string` as a whole *word*, for instance so as not to count the `follower` in `followers` or `followership`, you can add the `-w` option to those grep commands above. In effect that will look for occurrences of `follower` that are neither preceded nor followed by letters, digits or underscores (so called *word characters*). To also avoid counting `anti-follower`, you'll need to do the exclusion by hand:

```
count=$(
  cmd | grep -Poe "(?<![\w-])\Q$string\E(?![\w-])" | wc -l
)
```

---

However here, your problems are more about basic shell syntax.

To store the output of a command (minus the trailing newline characters) in a shell variable:

```
variable=$(cmd)
```

(no space on either side of `=`, and avoid the antiquated `` variable=`cmd` `` syntax).

To print the contents of a variable followed by one newline character, so as to feed to a command like those `grep` ones above:

```
printf '%s\n' "$variable" | grep ...
```

(don't use `echo`, remember to quote your parameter expansions when in list contexts)

Though in bash and other shells that have borrowed zsh's `<<<` operator, you can also do:

```
<<< "$variable" grep ...
```

In any case, if the aim is to check whether a variable contains at least one occurrence of the string, it should just be (with standard shell syntax):

```
case $variable in
  (*"$string"*) echo variable contains the string;;
  (*) echo It does not;;
esac
```

(here `$string` may contain newline characters).

Or to check it in the output of `cmd`:

```
if
  cmd | grep -qFe "$string"
then
  echo cmd output contains the string
else
  echo it does not
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required output in below command

```
/app/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh status  \
  | awk '{print gsub("follower",$0)}'
```

It will display how many times word "follower" occurs , In this example Considering output is a single line

Comment: your gsub() should be `gsub("follower", "")`, also note that based on OP accepted answer, that sounds xe wants count the total number of the word `follower` in a output, not count for every line of output. so you need count them all and print the total at the END

Comment: grep -c "follower" will show count of lines whre follower content occurs, Suppose in output is single line follower occurs 3 times, As per question it shuld show 3 , but it will show  1

Answer (score 0):

In (GNU) awk, set the RS to the word that you want to count and print `NR-1` at the end.

`cmd | awk -vRS='follower' 'END{print NR-1}'`

Comment: Note that it gives 0 on the output of `printf 'whatever follower'`. It shouldn't be a problem if the output of `cmd` is valid text though (does end in a newline character unlike the output of that `printf` command). You could change it to `awk -vRS='follower' 'END{print NR-(NR&&RT=="")}'` to account for (non-text) outputs ending in `follower`